# One word for knowledge in a specific profession/domain

Tags: word-request

The title pretty much says it all. I can't think of the word right now but I know it when I see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word  you  are  looking is:

Expert  or  Expertise.

Here  is the link

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expert